# How to test rest API with large json

Tags: json, rest

I am writing rest api with Flask. One of my endpoints handles a post request. One field of the request JSON 'audio' is supposed to contain the BASE64 encoded PCM file (audio format). If save this field to a file, it is about 200KB.

It might be too big to copy and paste in Swagger or Postman for testing. Even worse with curl command. Is there any good way to test with really big JSON in the request.

Comment: By test, do you mean unit test? Or do you mean manual test -- curl/postman/etc?

Comment: @SuperSaiyan The latter

Comment: You said "one of the fields". Depends on how the server wants to have the request encoded. If its multipart, may be use `curl -F'field=@audio-base64-file-path` ? If its JSON dump the entire request body to a file and then use `curl -d @file-path` and set the content type header.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a great tool called [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/). You can send point it to any file to send it as a HTTP request. You can change the Content-Type header to be `application/json` and select your JSON data file. [Here's a screenshot of what the program looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdakb.png)